# ActionBar button to right of Home

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to place a button (home) to the right of the back arrow on my action bar.  Requirement is that the left arrow (typically the home button) be captured and perform an onBackPressed which I have working.  Now how do I add a button to the right of the left arrow so that when I tap it I can capture it on the onOptionsItemSelected and have it perform the Home function.  I tried to create a relative layout with a single image view in it as a test, and then after infating the view setting it with actionBar.setCustomView(v);  however it does appear to show up.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bookmark_home_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**So ended up creating a custom actionbar as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bookmark_actionbar_left_btn"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_back" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bookmark_actionbar_logo_btn"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in the onCreate

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.bookmark_actionbar);

ImageButton goBackBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_actionbar_left_btn);
    goBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

ImageButton goHomeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_actionbar_subrosa_btn);
    goHomeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(BookmarkList.this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could add `ImageView` directly in your `Toolbar` xml. And then maybe with some gravity setup set image next to left arrow. For example it will go like this:
`<Toolbar> <ImageView/> </Toolbar>`

Comment: Piece of advice use a `Toolbar`!

Comment: So I ended up using a custom ActionBar see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a Custom ActionBar - See Update Above